# Indexing files with curl and SOLR

Tags: solr, indexing, tomcat6

I have setup a SOLR server, with tomcat6. Everything is working correctly and through the admin I can import documents.

However, I want to index documents from the shell. I have tried the following commands. This command works, where I put in the data in the curl command

```
curl http://localhost:8080/solr/shoeclub/update?commit=true -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data-binary '<add><doc><field name="id">1110.1.100733</field><field name="title">Peter Kaiser 23701 Zwart</field></doc><doc><field name="id">1110.1.101361</field><field name="title">Unisa Wonte Zwart</field></doc></add>'
```

This command does not work, in where I post the data with an xml file (which has the exact same content (copy/pasted it) as the xml-data in the command above.

```
curl http://vanassem.keytoe.nl:8080/solr/shoeclub/update --data-binary @shoeclub.xml -H "Content-Type: text/xml"
```

I have set up the file permissions on the xml-file to the tomcat user, so there should be no problem either. However, the data from the xml-file does not get posted in the index. Why?

Answer (score 3):

The document is being indexed in the second curl example. However, since you do not have the `commit=true` querystring parameter added to the second url, the document is not visible in the index until it is committed. Add the `commit=true` query string parameter and you should see your document that is defined in the xml file.

Here is a good reference for [Near Real Time Searching in Solr](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Near+Real+Time+Searching) that covers some of the commit strategies that you can use to determine when documents are visible within the index.

Comment: Ok, guess I should have thought about that. The querystring with commit=true is working perfectly.

Another question though: when I try to repeat the same command with a csv update, the index again is not updated.

`curl "http://vanassem.keytoe.nl:8080/solr/shoeclub/update/csv?commit=true&overwrite=true" --data-binary @test2.csv -H "Content-Type: application/csv;charset=utf-8"`

Comment: The `update/csv` handler is for legacy CSV support from older versions of Solr. The standard `update` handler supports CSV. Try using `curl "http://vanassem.keytoe.nl:8080/solr/shoeclub/update?commit=true&overwrite=t‌​rue" --data-binary @test2.csv -H "Content-Type: application/csv;charset=utf-8"` instead.

Comment: No, unfortunately that is not working either. I have worked on a work-around, in which I convert the csv to a indexable xml-file with python. That seems to work best.